# Can't load assets from public folder in development mode in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am new to webpack. I am trying to access my assets file outside of the src folder during development mode. The only solution I found in the internet is using copy-webpack-plugin. But I think that is for build. But since I am in development mode all things will load into memory. I might be wrong.
This is my file structure right now
[File Sturcutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzn3I.png)

And I am trying to access those file in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Fuse React - Material design admin template with pre-built apps and pages" />
        <meta
            name="keywords"
            content="React,Redux,Material UI Next,Material,Material Design,Google Material Design,HTML,CSS,Firebase,Authentication,Material Redux Theme,Material Redux Template"
        />
        <meta name="author" content="Withinpixels" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <base href

        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />

        <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIconsOutlined.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!--        <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIcons.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
        <!--        <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIconsRound.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
        <!--        <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIconsSharp.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
        <!--        <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/fonts/material-design-icons/MaterialIconsTwoTone.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

        <link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/fonts/meteocons/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <noscript id="jss-insertion-point"></noscript>
        <title>Fuse React - Material Design Admin Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
        <div id="root" class="flex">
            <!-- FUSE Splash Screen -->
            <div id="fuse-splash-screen">
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img width="128" src="assets/images/logos/fuse.svg" alt="logo" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Material Design Spinner -->
                    <div class="spinner-wrapper">
                        <div class="spinner">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="gap"></div>
                                <div class="left">
                                    <div class="half-circle"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <div class="half-circle"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- / Material Design Spinner -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / FUSE Splash Screen -->
        </div>
        <!--
          This HTML file is a template.
          If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

          You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
          The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

          To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
          To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my webpack config file

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const PUBLIC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, './public');
const PUBLIC_URL = process.env.PUBLIC_URL || '/';
const HTML_TEMPLATE = 'index.html';

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    // MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            ident: 'postcss',
                            plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            // template: `${PUBLIC_DIR}/${HTML_TEMPLATE}`,
            template: './public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            templateParameters: {
                PUBLIC_URL
            }
        })
        // new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@fuse': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/@fuse/'),
            '@history': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/@history/'),
            '@lodash': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/@lodash'),
            i18n: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/i18n'),
            app: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/app/')
        }
    }
};
```

NB: I am using react@17.0.2, webpack@4.43.0

Comment: you are not importing any image... the only reference to your images is on the template `index.html`.

Comment: @LeandroWilliam can you give me a reference about where should I import the images.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack just loads images that was in the **webpack** flow... If you want to copy extra assets you will need plugins like *`copy-webpack-plugin`* as you say.

loaders:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
}
```

Just would copy the `*..(jpg|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)` files that are imported in tree generated by the entry (`entry: './src/index.js'`). In your case the image was imported in the index.html file, which is not in the file tree generated by the **webpack** `entry`. If you import that image on `'./src/index.js'` you will see the image in the output folder `dist`